# How to calculate Jacobian in case of this

Tags: calculus

Now,

$x=\frac{sin(a)}{cos(b)}$,

$y=\frac{sin(b)}{cos(a)}$

I want to calculate Jacobian.
Please teach me how to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to calculate the Jacobian of
$$(x(a,b),y(a,b))=\Bigg(\dfrac{\sin a}{\cos b},\dfrac{\sin b}{\cos a}\Bigg).$$
First we have to compute the partial derivatives of $x(a,b)$ and $y(a,b)$, so
$$x'_a=\dfrac{\cos a}{\cos b}\text{ and }x'_b=\sin a \tan b \sec b$$
$$y'_a=\sin b\tan a \sec a\text{ and }y'_b=\dfrac{\cos b}{\cos a}$$
so the jacobian is given by
$$\mathrm J=\begin{pmatrix}x_a' &x_b'\\y_a'& y_b' \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\cos a}{\cos b}&&\sin a \tan b \sec b\\\sin b\tan a \sec a&&\dfrac{\cos b}{\cos a} \end{pmatrix}.$$